# Aptana - the selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches

Tags: python, python-3.x, aptana

I am Using Aptana to work on python 3.1.when I hit the run button, I got an error as shown below

How can I fix it?

for command prompt and my GUI it works better unless I tried to do some exercise on Aptana, i got this error

[image: python error on aptana]

Comment: `print "Hello World"` isn't valid Python-3 code, but that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Yea its  print("Hello World")...do i have to select the right path of the file within the aptana?.